# How to subset a pandas dataframe based on column names of another dataframe that may be in random order?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to subset the row names of the `raw_clin` dataframe by the column names of the `common` dataframe.

`common` dataframe example

```
common = pd.DataFrame([["PPP1R15A", -0.5880, 1.3980, -0.9402, -0.3741], ["AVPR1A", 1.5472, -0.8588, -0.1703, -0.5198], ["RGR", -0.3225, 0.8372, 0.2006, -0.0271]], columns=['Hugo_Symbol', 'TCGA-02-0010-01', 'TCGA-41-2571-01', 'TCGA-14-1821-01', 'TCGA-32-2632-01'])
```

`raw_clin` dataframe example

```
raw_clin = pd.DataFrame([["TCGA-02-0010-01", "I", "want", "to", "subset"], ["TCGA-14-1821-01", "clin_var", "rownames", "by", "common"], ["TCGA-41-2571-01", "colnames", "where", "the", "latter"], ["TCGA-32-2632-01", "may", "be", "random", "order"]], columns=['PATIENT_ID', 'Something1', 'something2', 'something3', 'something4'])
```

desired output

```
raw_clin = pd.DataFrame([["TCGA-02-0010-01", "I", "want", "to", "subset"], ["TCGA-41-2571-01", "colnames", "where", "the", "latter"], ["TCGA-14-1821-01", "clin_var", "rownames", "by", "common"], ["TCGA-32-2632-01", "may", "be", "random", "order"]], columns=['PATIENT_ID', 'Something1', 'something2', 'something3', 'something4'])
```

My attempt yielded no matches:

```
raw_clin = raw_clin[raw_clin.index.isin(common.columns)]
```

Comment: So: `raw_clin[row['PATIENT_ID'].isin(common.columns)]` ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you are mentioning row name which is index, then you need to use `set_index` for that dataframe.

Then your code will work `raw_clin = raw_clin[raw_clin.index.isin(common.columns)]` to create your desired output.

```
raw_clin = pd.DataFrame([["TCGA-02-0010-01", "I", "want", "to", "subset"], ["TCGA-14-1821-01", "clin_var", "rownames", "by", "common"], ["TCGA-41-2571-01", "colnames", "where", "the", "latter"], ["TCGA-32-2632-01", "may", "be", "random", "order"]], columns=['PATIENT_ID', 'Something1', 'something2', 'something3', 'something4']).set_index('PATIENT_ID')
```

Comment: The index of `raw_clin` and the columns of `common` are in random order. I want to match without considering order. My code possibly failed to return any rows/matches perhaps due to the order.

Comment: The code that you shared is exactly what I added in my question.